# How can i render and work with custom HTML tags like <g:plusone />?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dhtml

I see google is using its custom tag  and i know google is using javascript to render iframe instead of this tag, it is intresting and i want to know how can i have my own custom tag using javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've been able to have custom tags for awhile by namespacing the XML in your doctype. For example, facebook does it like this:

```
    xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"
```

Beware though, IMO custom tags are a BAD idea. It defeats the whole purpose of having standards and can wreak havoc on maintenance. Make sure you really weigh the pros and cons before going this route.

Comment: Interesting, so why google is using custom tags? I'm so curious what was their reason to use such thing!!